# Android Firebase Database Obfuscated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I recently updated my gradle files and I keep getting this error. Initially, everything was working perfectly but after the update, I can't write or read the Firebase Database. Have tried reverting back to the gradle initial state and the error wont go.

```
2018-09-28 12:11:34.092 14743-14743/ke.co.malezi.chemshabongo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw$zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:663)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw$zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:663)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw$zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:663)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw$zza.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:663)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:141)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzbw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:292)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:166)
        at ke.co.malezi.chemshabongo.ui.activity.MainActivity.updateOnlineStatus(MainActivity.java:240)
        at ke.co.malezi.chemshabongo.ui.activity.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:228)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6796)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3546)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2795)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

project gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

builde gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
```

Comment: that's only part of the error, we need to see the rest, especially the part above this part

Comment: @TimCastelijns the error log is now updated

Comment: Please add the entire build.gradle file, not only those implementations.

Comment: @FredrickOchieng did you find any solution?